# How to make a whatsapp style more button menu iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am unsure as to what the menu is named, the one that has a list of options and pops up from the bottom of the screen. It looks like this: [image]

How do I create one in swift, and what is it called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an `UIAlertController` with the preferred style of `actionSheet`:

```
@IBAction func showActionSheet(_ sender : AnyObject) {
    // Print out what button was tapped
    func printActionTitle(_ action: UIAlertAction) {
        print("You tapped \(action.title!)")
    }

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Mute", style: .default, handler: printActionTitle))
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Contact Info", style: .default, handler: printActionTitle))
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Delete Chat", style: .destructive, handler: printActionTitle))
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: printActionTitle))
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```